# VB 2010 compare string within directory and store latest revision letter of the file name

Tags: vb.net, string, file, compare, filenames

My application currently extracts data from an excel document, putting the data into a listview.  I then am able to open each of the strings/items within the listview (which are pdf files in a given directory).  However the pdf files within the given directory have revision letters at the end of their file names, starting with 'A' for the first revision and 'B' for the second revision...and so on.
So I am trying to approach it like comparing the string to the files in the directory and then once it's found, check what the latest rev letter is if any.
So if there is 07010302A.pdf file in the directory and there's also a 07010302B.pdf in the directory, I want to store that file name (07010302B.pdf) to a new string in my vb application.  Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Here's what I am working with:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel



Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim range As Excel.Range
    Dim rCnt As Integer
    Dim cCnt As Integer
    Dim Obj As Object

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Exp_Master.xlsm")
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    range = xlWorkSheet.Range("H1:H100") 'xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

    For rCnt = 1 To range.Rows.Count
            For cCnt = 1 To range.Columns.Count
            Obj = CType(range.Cells(rCnt, cCnt), Excel.Range)
            If IsNumeric(CType(range.Cells(rCnt, cCnt), Excel.Range).Value) Then
                'MsgBox(Obj.value)
                ListView1.Items.Add(Obj.value)
                ListView1.View = View.List

            End If

        Next
    Next

    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)

    'Kill Excel Process that wouldn't close
    Process.Start("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\batch archive\EXCEL_KILLER.bat")

    'MsgBox("Total Item(s) in ListView:" & ListView1.Items.Count)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Dim str As String



    For i = 1 To (ListView1.Items.Count)
        Dim strng As String = "R:\"
        n = (i - 1)
        str = strng & (ListView1.Items.Item(n).Text) & (".pdf")
        MsgBox(str)
        '----
        'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(str)
        'Here I want to check the R:\ directory and compare it with each string to see
        'what the latest revision letter of the filename is and store it in another string to add to
        'a pdf merging list later in this for loop
        '----
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Just do a [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) with a search pattern. Ex: 07010302?.pdf   Also, I highly suggest you separate your logic into smaller function that have specific task.

Comment: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj)` is what you should be using. It is also done in reverse order of objects created.

Comment: @OneFineDay Thanks, that seemed to work fine for the kill process.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @the_lotus Doesn't that just get the count of files that contain that search criteria?  Not sure that helps me get the latest alphabetical rev letter whether it be C, or D, or H after the main filestring.

Comment: @cheapkid1 this returns the list of all the files with a specific filter. After you have the list, you can easily loop or sort and figure out the greatest letter.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use your Directory.getfiles suggestion and I added a for loop to display only the last of the files labeled within that criteria.  Thanks a bunch, just took a little more playing with it to determine what I actually wanted and how to put it in code.

If anyone cares, here is the update that works and gets the last file name and path of the directory.getfiles group within a search criteria.

Cheers!

```
 For i = 1 To (ListView1.Items.Count)
        Dim strng As String = "R:\"
        n = (i - 1)
        str = strng & (ListView1.Items.Item(n).Text) & (".pdf")
        'MsgBox(str)
        Dim substr As String
        substr = str.Substring(3, 8)
        'MsgBox(substr)
        '----
        'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(str)

        ' Only get files that begin with... 
        Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles("R:\", (substr & ("*.pdf")))
        'MsgBox("The number of files starting with your string is {0}.", dirs.Length)
        Dim dir As String

        For Each dir In dirs
            If dir Is dirs.Last Then
                MsgBox(dir)
                'do something with your last item'
            End If
        Next

        '----
    Next
End Sub
```